# Show all pending tasks in Create new child branch

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

How can I display all pendings tasks in Plastic SCM when create a new
child branch?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Goto `Preferences` -> `Issue trackers` -> `Issue query limit` and set your display limit. (e.g. 100)